# How can we use Chainlink's CCIP with our own token contracts?

Tags: chainlink

I tried Chainlink's Cross-Chain Interoperability Protocol (CCIP) via their starter kit at
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/ccip-starter-kit-hardhat.

It worked well for the CCIP-BnM test token that they supplied.

But when I tried a token that I created the error message "not in the list of supportedTokens" appears.

So can we use CCIP for our own token, or will there only ever be a small list hand-picked by Chainlink?

Is deploying our own Router contract supported?

If there is or will be a way to use CCIP with our own token, would it need to have particilar code for it to be compatible? e.g. I noticed in the CCIP-BnM token contract that it inherits `ERC677`. So would our contract have to do so as well, or is it optional? `ERC677` has had bad press due to reentrancy attacks.

I've read through documentation but there are no answers to my questions.

Axelar's Interchain Token Service appears to be much more flexible as it supports any ERC20 token by design.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with Axelar you have the option to deploy a custom token or a wrapped token that is linked to your main erc20 token on your origin chain. ITS uses token managers as sort of a "partner" for your contract on the chain where your token contract exists. The token manager handles the "interchain logic" (sending the token from one chain to another). Here is a portal that is available to play around with ITS services on testnet
https://testnet.interchain.axelar.dev/

Comment: Yes, I'm quite familiar with Axelar already, but wanted to try ChainLink with custom tokens.